# 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: foreach

I am trying to make a conection to a database  that I made on `sqlservermanagement`

I have make a console application on visual studio 2012

I have this statement

```
  foreach (DataRow pRow in persoaneSet.Tables["persoane"].Rows)
  {
    Console.Write("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", pRow["nrcrt"],pRow["nume"],pRow["codc"]);
    foreach (DataRow cRow in pRow.GetParentRow(relPersCrt)) // **here is the error**
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", cRow["autor"],cRow["titlu"],cRow["cota"]);
    }
  }
```

Here I have to conect table one to table 2 from my database and here table 1 and I had made like my teacher but unfortunately i recive Error

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataRow' because 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

What must I do here ?

The example of teacher it's working but not mine

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `foreach` as there is only one parent row. Try:

```
foreach (DataRow pRow in persoaneSet.Tables["persoane"].Rows)
{
    Console.Write("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", pRow["nrcrt"],pRow["nume"],pRow["codc"]);

    DataRow cRow = pRow.GetParentRow(relPersCrt);
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", cRow["autor"],cRow["titlu"],cRow["cota"]);
}
```

Also, you should consider adding extra checks as your code is very prone to unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use foreach with something which implements the IEnumerable interface. Basically you can only iterate over a collection of things, not a single thing. Your first foreach iterates over a collection of rows, with the second one you're trying to iterate over a single row.